# BroadcastReceiver not getting called when App is killed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcastreceiver

I am using BroadCastReceiver to listen to GCM Messages. I want my notification to arrive even when the app is killed and phone is locked. But my broadcast receiver's onReceive is not getting triggered when app is killed , although it's working properly when app is in background.
I have declared my BroadCastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml and do not unregister broadcast receiver manually anywhere in the app.

GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
PowerManager powermanager;
WakeLock wakeLock;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    powermanager=  ((PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
    wakeLock=powermanager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    Log.d("GCM broadcast receiver", intent+"");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    System.out.println("MESSAGE IS---->>>"+msg);

    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tcs.hcp_android"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2" >

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="120"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android"
    android:label="my_permission"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" >
</permission>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >

    <!-- added by disha  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" > -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:permission="com.tcs.hcp_android" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android.Offline"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="com.tcs.hcp_android"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android.NotificationDismissedReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android.NotificationSend"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.tcs.hcp_android.GCMNotificationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="com.tcs.hcp_android"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true" />
</application>
```

Comment: Receiving  Log messages or not?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK No. Nothing is coming.

Answer (score 0):

The latter may seem relatively extraordinary: Why do we really want to stop the service that we want to keep alive? Because if we do not stop it, the service will die with our app. Instead, by stopping the service, we will force the service to call on our own Destroy, which will force the app to rebuild it after it is dead.
Here is the service:

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("ActivityRecognition.RestartSensor");
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    stoptimertask();
}
```